# Why covalently bonded molecules have strong bonds within the molecule?

Tags: bond, molecules, covalent-compounds

While studying the chapter carbon and it's compounds in NCERT page 60
I came across this line:

> Covalently bonded molecules are seen to have strong bonds within the
> molecule but intermolecular forces are weak. This gives rise to low
> melting and boiling points of these compounds

While I do understand that the atoms in the covalent bond are held together by the attractive force between the shared electron pairs and the nucleus of the atoms in the molecule , I have failed to understand why covalently bonded molecules have strong bonds within  the molecule?

So I searched on the internet and went through some books but couldn't find any understandable answer. Could someone please explain why do covalently bonded molecules have strong bonds within the molecule but weak intermolecular forces?

Comment: Explain what about it? The division between inter- and intramolecular interactions is somewhat arbitrary. Some covalent bonds are way weaker then other, some interactions usually considered weak can become quite strong. To get a good answer you need to know what you really what to know.

Answer (score 2):

Intermolecular forces, also called van der Wals forces, are rather weak, because they are due to electric interactions between charges which are far away from one another. The nucleus of an atom attracts strongly its own electrons ; it also attracts electrons belonging to other atoms, farther away. But the electric attraction force decreases with the square of the distance. So the attraction between the nucleus of any atom $\ce{A}$ included in a covalence $\ce{A-B}$ is still strong with the electrons of "its" $\ce{B}$ atom, because $\ce{A}$ is next to $\ce{B}$. But the attraction is weak with any other $\ce{A}$, $\ce{B}$ or $\ce{X}$ atom if this atom belongs to another molecule, because of the distance.

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone please explain why do covalently bonded molecules have strong bonds within the molecule but weak intermolecular forces?

Intermolecular bonds are weaker (or more fleeting) than intramolecular bonds by definition. The intramolecular bonds define a molecule. They persist when a molecule diffuses in solution, or when a molecule changes from one physical state to another (or from one phase to another). On the other hand, the intermolecular bonds can break and reform during these processes. When an intramolecular bond is formed or broken, we say there is a chemical reaction.

> > Covalently bonded molecules are seen to have strong bonds within the molecule but intermolecular forces are weak. This gives rise to low melting and boiling points of these compounds

This statement makes sense if we compare and contrast ionic compounds and molecular compounds. For the simplest examples, ionic compounds will have higher melting and boiling points than molecular compounds. For example, the only type of bond present in the ionic compound sodium chloride is the ionic bond between sodium and chloride. In order to melt sodium chloride, you have to break these bonds. On the other hand, to boil a molecular compound like acetone only the fairly weak intermolecular bonds will break (in this case dipole-dipole interactions) while the covalent bonds remain, ensuring that acetone as a liquid and as a gas has the same molecular structure.