# Covalent compounds-What are the reasons for attraction between atoms to be strong...?

Tags: bond, covalent-compounds

In general, most of the covalent compounds are known to have low boiling point and melting point due to the weak Van der Waals forces between molecules in them, requiring lesser heat to break the bond.

The weak VdW forces is due to strong covalent bond within their molecule (or maybe due to the atoms are held tightly to each other...)

Here is the question:
What is the reason for covalent bond or attraction force between atoms in them to be strong?

Comment: Have you read covalent bond pages on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_bond) or  [libretexts.org](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Chemical_Bonding/Fundamentals_of_Chemical_Bonding/Covalent_Bonds) ?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/165469/why-covalently-bonded-molecules-have-strong-bonds-within-the-molecule https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/11048/are-metallic-ionic-bonds-weaker-than-covalent-bonds

Comment: Your definition of "covalent compound" is suspect. Iodine and menthol are both covalent compounds by your definition and are volatile or low melting point solids. But diamond and kevlar are also normally thought of as covalent compounds but are both strong and not remotely volatile. So what was the question again?

Comment: @matt_black What is the reason of attraction force between atoms to be strong in covalent compound ?(diamond and silica etc. are exceptions)

Comment: Are you asking why a *covalent bond* is strong? (That has not much to do with boiling points or melting points, so it's likely that your first paragraph is confusing)

Comment: @orthocresol Hmm..to be honest,yes.Undeniably,the first paragraph is really messy.(I will try better next time)

Comment: It is simple just ignore the QM complications. The electrons in a bond are in lowere energy orbitals when they can be attracted to 2 [or more] nuclei. The amount of shielding  and the orbital shapes determines the bond strengths. Imagine walking with your sig other occasionally bumping each other, weak intermolecular attraction, hold hands a weak molecular bond, the nuclei are still far apart[think

Comment: I2 molecules Get in close a good strong Hug,  a 4 armed multiple bond. Now give a good hard squeeze your other goes OUCH and springs back the nuclei got too close together and the bond electrons got squeezed out of their orbitals. You really do not need QM but it does explain things